# Problem with repeating objects in array when already in the array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the player moves forward then the GameObject paint is instantiated and stored in the array, even if the object paint is already in the array.

How can I stop the object paint from being stored in the array more than once?

```
public GameObject[] array;
public GameObject paint;
int temp = 0;
private RaycastHit hit;

public float speed = 10f;                             
public Text levelText;
public GameObject paint;
float maxdistance = 0.51f; 
Vector3 newtargetposition;
bool pos;

private void FixedUpdate()
{

 if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forw ard,out hit, maxdistance))
 {
    if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
            move = false;                                                                         
    }

    if (move)
    {
        PlayerMove();                         
    }
 }
}

public void PlayerMove()
{
    if (move)
    {
      vector3 positions = transform.position + new Vector3(0f, -0.5f,0f); //when player move then paint instantiate y position 

        array[temp] = Instantiate<GameObject>(paint, position, Quaternion.identity);
        temp++;

        newtargetposition=position;
        Debug.Log("newtargetposiiton:" + newtargetposition);

        if (temp == 150)    
        {
            if (newtargetposition == position)
            {
                //what can i do here
                //i dont want to paint here because position store in newtargetposition,it is repeat
                //array[temp]--;
                Debug.Log("newtargetpositions:" + newtargetposition);
                //temp--;
            }
            gameOver.SetActive(true);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove repeated instantiation of the object and repeated objects in the array?

Comment: This question is unclear in it's current state. Use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55948746/edit) link to edit your question and fix the code part. Without that I doubt that anyone can understand what is your problem.

Comment: Yeah, because your code just places a paint reference in the array at the array position/index given by `temp`. Nowhere does your code even attempt to check whether the paint in question is already stored in the array. If you don't want add the same paint multiple times to the array, maybe you should think about how you can code/implement such a check (You might also want to learn about other collection types in .NET, such as HashSet<T>, for example. The HashSet<T> collection naturally does not permit duplicate entries.)

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171520/problem-with-repeating-objects-in-array-when-already-in-the-array  check this link

Comment: I think the problem is not about removing but more about preventing multiple drawing. So once one is drawn, you'd need an extra condition for additional drawing, for instance that current position and last object position is greater than x.

Comment: @Everts  can u edit my code,i m using hashset HashSet<Vector3> paintPositions; but nothing happen  if (!paintPositions.Contains(position)){} found then instantiate but position found then what????

Comment: Have you tried to set move to false at the end of the method?

Comment: @Everts can u help because i m various method apply but nothing will happen??currently paint object store in list??help..  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171450/how-to-detect-when-the-player-has-filled-a-shape

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be how you would go about it although I know loops are very inefficient it is probably the best way to deal with your problem as of now

```
if (move)
        {
         //boolean is created to return if paint is in the array
            bool blnUnique = true;
            foreach (GameObject temp in array)
            {
                if (temp == paint)
                {
                    blnUnique = false;
                }
            }

            if (blnUnique)
            {

                vector3 positions = transform.position + new Vector3(0f, -0.5f, 0f); //when player move then paint instantiate y position 

                array[temp] = Instantiate<GameObject>(paint, position, Quaternion.identity);
                temp++;

                newtargetposition = position;
                Debug.Log("newtargetposiiton:" + newtargetposition);

                if (temp == 150)
                {
                    if (newtargetposition == position)
                    {
                        //what can i do here
                        //i dont want to paint here because position store in newtargetposition,it is repeat
                        //array[temp]--;
                        Debug.Log("newtargetpositions:" + newtargetposition);
                        //temp--;
                    }
                    gameOver.SetActive(true);
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
                }
            }
        }
```

And to remove any repeated values

```
    private void CleanArray(ref GameObject[] array)
    {
        GameObject[] goTemp = new GameObject[0];
        bool blnFirst = true;
        bool blnTracker = false;
        foreach (GameObject V in array)
        {
            //This is to make sure that there is some value in temp to test against

            if (blnFirst)
            {

                Array.Resize(ref goTemp, goTemp.Length + 1);
                goTemp[goTemp.Length - 1] = V;
                blnFirst = false;
            }

            blnTracker = true;

            foreach (GameObject T in Temp)
            {
                if (T == V)
                {
                    blnTracker = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(blnTracker)

            {
                Array.Resize(ref goTemp, goTemp.Length + 1);
                goTemp[goTemp.Length - 1] = V;
            }
        }
        array = goTemp;
    }
```

Personal this would be how I would go about it but I don't usually work with unity and gameobjects so it may not work as intended, but the remove function and catch both work for integers and smaller, less complex data types.